# Send push notification from one Android device to other Using GCM

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I am been using Parse for sending push notifications earlier and that does not seem to work well. I heard from the internet that we can send push notifications from one android device to another using `GCM` and I followed this [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/). Before I get to implement it, I just need to know whether, we can send push notification from an Android device to another using this service.

I have the following doubts

1. How do I send the push notification to a specific device using another device with the help of GCM ?
2. What is the unique identifier that I must be using if the above question is possible ?
3. Should I implement my own backend to save the unique identifiers about which the above question states ? Or is there a way that GCM can handle for me ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answers to all your questions are in the documentation itself.

1) Send Upstream message from Device A to the server and send Downstream message from server to Device B.
2) [Instance ID API](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/) will provide a token which is the unique identifier.
3) Yes you have to implement you server that will communicate with GCM connection server.

All of which is explained on [the overview page](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/gcm) itself.

I hope this answers your question. There is also [a sample](https://github.com/google/gcm) you can refer to.

Also, a tutorial [here](http://androidexample.com/Device_To_Device_Messaging_Using_Google_Cloud_Messaging_GCM_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=122&aaid=142).